# Calculus: Diffeomorphisms

Tags: calculus

**Problem**
Consider the map $(u,v)=F(x,y)=(x+x^2,y-xy)$. Take a positive number $r>0$ and let $D_r$ be the disk of radius $r$ around the origin in the $x,y$-plane, and let $U_r=F(D_r)$ be its image in the $u,v$-plane. Prove that if $r$ is small enough then $F$ is a diffeomorphism from $D_r$ to $U_r$. Find the area of $U_r$ for all such small enough $r$.

**Attempt**
So this is a sample exam question I could get. I understand the theory of what a diffeomorphism is, in that it is an invertible function that maps one manifold to another. So F needs to be bijective and its inverse differentiable. However I'm unsure on how this proof should be answered as we weren't given the proof in class and I'm not particularly fluent in these proof type questions. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Calculate $dF(0,0).$ If it's nonsingular, apply the inverse function theorem, which will say that in some neighborhood of $(0,0),$ you get what you need.

Comment: So I get a $2X2$ matrix with top line $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}=(1+2x, -y)$ and bottom line $\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}=(0, 1-x)$. What do I say next?

Comment: So at the point $(x,y)=(0,0)$, $dF$ is nonsingular. As zhw suggested, use inverse function theorem, or look it up if you're unfamiliar with it.

Comment: So I get the determinant and show its non-zero? Where does the $r$ come into it?